# Flutter：How to create a full screen mask view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Now I'm using the showModalBottomSheet,

when I click on the semi-transparent bottomsheet, it pops this view out, but what I want is that it doesn't respond to the user's click and still stays there, how do I do that?

How to create a full screen mask view?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user click on - semi-transparent  area - `ModalBottomSheet` won't close using - `WillPopScope`

```
showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return WillPopScope(  // add this
                    onWillPop: () async => false,
                    child: Container()); // your code continues
              });
```